# Angularjs - IE8 in IE7 modus (and in IE8 compatibility modus) not working properly

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs

I'm having a little problem with Angularjs version 1.0.1. I created an app and tested it in IE8 in IE7 modus and it is not listening to ng-change nor ng-click, didn't test other handles but at least those two don't work for me... (**all other browsers are just fine**) I hope you guys can help me with this, or maybe I'm missing something here... Is there a special treatment for IE7/8?

Here you see the controller:

```
CalculatorCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.btw = 1;
    $scope.input = 0.00;
    $scope.output = 0.00;

    $scope.getBedrag = function() {
        var input = $scope.input;
        var btw = $scope.btw;       
        var output = 0.0;

        if(input != 0) {
            input = parseFloat(input.replace (",", "."));
            var tmp = input+"";
            $scope.input = tmp.replace(".", ",");
        }

        if($scope.isNumber(input)) {
            output = $scope.calculateBedrag(input);

            if(btw == 1) output = output * 1.19;

            $scope.output = output.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
        } else {
            //alert('Voer een bedrag in a.u.b.');
            $scope.input = 0;
            $scope.output = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the html I simply use:

```
<input autocomplete="off" ng-model="input" class="x-width" type="text" name="bedrag" value="" ng-change="getBedrag()" />
<input class="x-width" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="bedrag" value="{{output}}" />
```

Hope someone can help me :)

**Edit:**
Wel I tried IE Tester to in IE7 modus, didn't work either. I don't have any machine with *real* IE7 on it, so I can't test that...

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure your application follows the IE guidelines listed in the docs. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score 0):

Well, the docs say:

> "Webkit-based browsers (Safari, Chrome, iPhone, Android, WebOS,
>   BlackBerry 6), Firefox, IE6 and above. Note that CSS only works on IE7
>   and above."

So it should be working OK. Compatibility modes are kinda weird though, and I'd be surprised if they tested it in that mode.

I can't really imagine why you'd need it work in that mode – if you are on an intranet, you can change IE's settings via group policy (as far as I can recall) to stop it using the compat mode.

Comment: Wel I tried IE Tester to in IE7 modus, didn't work either. I don't have any machine with *real* IE7 on it...

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to use classes to define your Angular mark up. For example:

`<div class="ng-controller:CalculatorCtrl">`

Instead of

`<div ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl">`